# Why is there no word meaning firearm in contemporary Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, weapons

I noticed that there is no word meaning firearm according to [this](http://latinlexicon.org/info.php) site.Why is this? I've tried synonyms such as gun and pistol but none work. Has no one gotten around to making one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It pains me to suggest that Latin Wikipedia is in error, but Latin Wikipedia is in error. The *arma ignifera* Nathanial suggests is in fact a word for firearm that some have used, but it's in the *silva* of the Morgan lexicon, not the *adumbratio*. The difference between the two is explained in [a short piece](https://www.academia.edu/11790987/Morgan-Owens_Lexicon_of_Neo-Latin) by the lexicon's current editor, Patrick Owens:

> The Morgan-Owens Latin Lexicon is found under the link entitled "adumbratio". The link entitled "silva" is a mere collection of other modern Latin dictionaries. If a term appears in the "silva" but not in the "adumbratio" it is because it has been intentionally rejected on philological grounds.

In the *adumbratio*, Morgan too went with *sclopetum* for a long gun and *pistola* for a short one, though I suspect *fistula* is better.

For "firearm" the only thing I've seen is *[manuballista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballista#Cheiroballistra_and_manuballista)*, which is a little too broad; it's the word the Romans used for the hand-held version of the *ballista*, a siege engine—so essentially a crossbow. If you're willing to include crossbows in your definition of "firearms" then *manuballista* is actually perfect.

Comment: Why do you like fistula better?

Comment: Because a teacher of mine once presented a very convincing argument that "pistola" was derived from "fistula." Unfortunately, all I have in my notes is "pistola<—fistula," so I can't share it here.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  Thanks for the distinction on silva vs. adumbratio; that's very helpful.

Comment: No problem. I actually only learned about it a month ago, at the Paideia Institute Living Latin in NYC conference.

Comment: The nice thing about "pistola" is that it's the same in Italian, which provides a nice bit of credibility.

Comment: Francis William Newman's translation of Robinson Crusoe into Classical Latin uses "ignipulta" for a gun, but it's definitely not official, and very old. In fact, the book was published in the 1800s.

Answer (score 5):

The Latin Wikipedia currently uses [*arma ignifera*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arma_ignifera), citing David Morgan's [*Lexicon Anglico-Latinum*](https://archive.org/stream/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon_djvu.txt).

Based on other lexicons, the Latin Wikipedia uses [*sclopetum*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sclopetum) for long guns, while pistols are [*pistolium*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistolium).

John C. Traupman uses *sclopetum* for both "gun" and "rifle" in his *Conversational Latin for Oral Proficiency* and Bantam *New College Dictionary*, but gives no entry for "pistol."