# What is a major subject in Latin

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, academic-latin

Simply, what is "major subject" in Latin?
By a major subject I mean the subject a university student mainly focuses on.
I have used the translation *materia principalis*, but I wonder if there is a more suitable one.
In particular, is (or was) a Latin expression for this already in use somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I need to translate relatively new words into Latin, I find that the [Morgan and Silva Furman University Lexicon](https://ia801000.us.archive.org/12/items/TheLexiconAnglumEtLatinumByDavidMorgan/MorganAndSilvaFurmanUniversityLexicon.pdf) is particularly useful. Here is the entry for "major", which is what we call a student's primary concentration in the U.S.

> .univ major in, specialize in / speciale studium (alicuius rei) amplecti |
>   major, specialization specializatio* [Latinitas] (HELF.)
>   .univ major, specialize / speciali studio se excolere (v. operam dare)
>   (LRL)

So, *specializatio* seems to be somewhat adequate in describing a "major". It obviously is related to the English "specialization", which makes sense for the purpose it serves.

Comment: Thanks! I think a better fit with those dictionary entries (and my sense of style, admittedly) would be *studium speciale*. It also has the benefit of relating it more clearly to the context of studying than *specializatio* would. I was unaware of that dictionary, but it looks useful.

Comment: It's worth noting that this definition comes from the *silva*, not the *adumbratio*. See [this answer](http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/511/12) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh, I'm well aware of the difference. As it says in the definition, it comes, in part, from _Latinitas Recens_, which is a somewhat credible source for modern Latin. I feel like the _silva_ is still useful, especially since there was no ancient equivalent, and there is nothing in the _adumbratio_ for this word.

Answer (score 2):

In the Medieval *studia generalia*, there were four "majors" one could study (although one of them was preliminary to the other three), and they were called ***facultates***.

What we think of today as a University actually began as a corporation (or guild) of teachers or of students in a certain city; those were called *universitates*: *u. magistrum* for a teachers' guild, and *u. scholarium* for a students' guild. Sometimes there was a single guild for both, called *universitas magistrum et scholarium*.

When one entered University, one studied the *trivium* and then the *quadrivium* within the *facultas artium*, or the faculty of the (Liberal) Arts. Once students had obtained their title of *Magister Artium*, they could leave University or continue into one of the other three *facultates*: Law, Medicine or Theology.

Obviously, there's the issue that, in North America, the term "faculty" is used to refer to the teaching body of an institution, the *corpus docens*. However, since they are different languages, there is no problem in using the closest historical term to the modern English concept — even if they really looked nothing like Anglophone majors do today.

In any case, during the High Middle Ages, the same term (*facultas*) was used both for the course taught and for the subset of the *universitas magistrum* which taught the same course, so the *facultas legis* or the *facultas medicinae* could refer to both the subject which the students enrolled in it studied or to the teachers who taught those subjects.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good option to keep in mind. In Finland the English word "faculty" is used in a yet different meaning. It does not refer to the personnel or the subject, but the university is divided into faculties and faculties into departments. A faculty is lead by a dean. I believe the typical corresponding term in the US would be "school". Do you know if *facultas* refers more to the institution teaching law, medicine, or theology, or to the subjects themselves?

Comment: The institution was only one; it was called either _studium particulare_, if only local students were admissible, or otherwise _studium generale_. The guilds of the teachers and of the students were called _universitas_ (the former _u. magistrum_; the latter _u. scholarium_). Within the _universitas magistrum_, there was a subset which taught Law, for instance, and those could be referred as the _facultas legis_, though the course (the "major") they taught was also the _facultas legis_. There wasn't then a clear distinction between the two.

Comment: Many thanks! Could you add that comment into your answer? That is very interesting, at least to me.